# Use POST method to get the text of a h7 tag using Django

Tags: python, django, ajax

I am using Ajax and a POST method to store a data. To validate the data I need to take some information from a h7 tag as shown in the next code. I defined a class and an id for the h7, but the output is None instead of the h7 tag value.

HTML Code:

```
<form class= "login_assignment" method="POST" id = "log_ass">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <br>
    <label><b>Name:</b></label> <h7 class = 'name'></h7>
    <br>
    <label><b>Last Name:</b></label> <h7 class = 'last_name'></h7>
    <br>
    <label><b>ID:</b></label> <h7 class = 'id_number' id = 'id_number'> 
    </h7>
    <br>
    <label><b>Mail</b></label> <h7 class = 'mail'></h7>
    <br>
    <label><b>Login Type</b></label> <h7 class = 'login'></h7> 
    <br>
    <input id = "modify" type="submit" value="Modify">
</form>
```

Ajax Code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $regform = $(".login_assignment")
    $regform.submit(function(event){
      var $formData = $("#log_ass").serialize()
      event.preventDefault()
      var $endpoint = window.location.href
      $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: '/user_login_assignment/',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: $formData,
        success: function(data){
          if (data == 'modified') {
            alert('The user access have been modified');
```

URL Code:

```
path('user_login_assignment/', views.user_login_assignment, name = 
'user_login_assignment')
```

View Code:

```
def user_login_assignment(request):
  if request.method == 'POST':
    id_parameter = request.POST.get('id_number')
    print(id_parameter)
    return JsonResponse('modified', safe = False)
```

Although the h7 tag looks empty, it actually receive information from an Ajax function, and once it received the text from the ajax function. the user press an input button and, I want this text from the h7 tag to be sent to the view function to identify a user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

foo should be what's inside the tag ...

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
            var foo = document.getElementById('id_number').textContent
            console.log(foo)
            var $regform = $(".login_assignment")
            $regform.submit(function(event){
             ...
```

Comment: do you know how the views function can accept this foo variable

Comment: Yeah, you can append it to the form.

Answer (score 1):

Django does not take post data from the id of html tag but rather with the name attribute, try replacing id with name if it works, although it should be an input to be passed in post request you can not send html elements on form submission.